# Implementing the soundcloud player

Tags: php, javascript, soundcloud

Is it possible to find the links in the text I have stored in my database, which start with www.soundcloud.com or http://soundcloud.com, determine, if they refer to the page with the song or not (for example soundcloud user profile) and if yes, to display soundcloud player instead of the link, like it is done on the facebook...?

Comment: I think my question is quite clear ....and I thank gryzzly for nice answer and useful help instead of downvoting or making an idiot from someone who absolutely doesn´t know how to do something :))))

Comment: You are not asking for help with any specific problem. SO is not intended to be a place to get your code written for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

You could query [oembed](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/oembed) service with your URL like this:

```
http://soundcloud.com/oembed.json?url=http://soundcloud.com/crystalfighters
```

Then it will either return the JSON with widget's HTML represented as `html` property

```
{
version: 1,
type: "rich",
provider_name: "SoundCloud",
provider_url: "http://soundcloud.com",
height: 450,
width: "100%",
title: "Crystal Fighters",
description: "http://facebook.com/crystalfighters BUY NEW ALBUM 'CAVE RAVE' NOW: hhttp://po.st/caveravebuy LIVE+DJ Bookings ex-US GregLowe@theagencygroup.com US bookings carter@windishagency.com Management info@giantmenmanagement.com",
thumbnail_url: "http://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000041667144-lcvdi5-t500x500.jpg?9d68d37",
html: "<iframe width="100%" height="450" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Fusers%2F114019&show_artwork=true"></iframe>",
author_name: "Crystal Fighters",
author_url: "http://soundcloud.com/crystalfighters"
}
```

or will return HTTP 404 which means this URL isn't a valid or public SoundCloud resource

Comment: Thank you, I added it to my page into a <a href=""> but it isn`t displaying the player, just some page with JSON, like you said, but I have no idea what to do with it :)) ...how to display that player?

Comment: echo '<a href="http://soundcloud.com/oembed?format=js&url=http://soundcloud.com/sirda/skaph-h-d-s&iframe=true" class="soundcloud-player">http://soundcloud.com/oembed?format=js&url=http://soundcloud.com/sirda/skaph-h-d-s&iframe=true</a>';

Comment: oh no, this is not how you should do that. the idea here is that with PHP you'd do a call to that `oembed` service, get JSON and echo only the response’s `html` property. You can use http://be2.php.net/file_get_contents to get JSON, http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php to decode that JSON and then just access property of the decoded object with square bracket notation like `obj['html']`

Comment: Now I got it like this: $track = file_get_contents('http://soundcloud.com/oembed?format=js&url=http://soundcloud.com/sirda/skaph-h-d-s&iframe=true');
$obj = json_decode($track);
echo $obj['html']; but the $obj isnt returning anything...var_dump says NULL...what do I do wrong?

Comment: it's `format=json`, `js` is for `jsonp`, also `iframe` is the default option, no need to add it now.

Comment: Yeah, that was the catch, thanks! One more question: How do I set the height of the player? I can control only width... see here: http://clickclack.cz/index.php?djs&id=1 ...the play button is displayed above the waveform...Is there some setting, which would display that button next to the waveform? Like on facebook...I want to save some space, this is too big :))

Comment: You can pass params in oembed, like `show_artwork=false` and `maxheight=130` to hide artwork in the widget and manipulate height so – http://soundcloud.com/oembed?format=json&url=http://soundcloud.com/sirda/skaph-h-d-s&show_artwork=false&maxheight=130 – but notice that widget's contents are 166px high, not much you could do about that